# Infer teacher-student relationships via courses?

Tags: rdf, sparql, owl, protege

I have created an ontology about a university, like the one discussed in [this series of YouTube videos.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wCsP36wFxdA)

There are classes and instances of students, professors and courses.  There are "studies" and "teaches" properties that relate students and professors to their classes.

```
<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#teaches"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#Cadbury"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#EL101"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>

<ObjectPropertyAssertion>
    <ObjectProperty IRI="#studies"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#Hechinger"/>
    <NamedIndividual IRI="#EL101"/>
</ObjectPropertyAssertion>
```

Is determining that Hechinger is a student of Cadbury something that I should be able to do with OWL reasoning or inference in Protege?

Comment: Without further axioms/rules this can not be inferred by a standard OWL reasoner.

Comment: @AKSW Thanks.  As a general-purpose (bioinformatics) programmer, is axiom/rule creation something that I could learn in a day or two?  Are there any training resources that you recommend?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is determining that Hechinger is a student of Cadbury something that I should be able to do with OWL reasoning or inference in Protege?

If you have a **isStudentOf** property, then you can define the axioms that would make this inference work.  E.g., in this case, you'd want to assert that the *chain*

**studies** • **teaches**<sup>-1</sup>

is a *subproperty* of **isStudentOf**.  That is, if a student studies a course, and then course is taught by some professor, then the student is a student of that professor.  Here's what it looks like in Protege:

[image: subproperty chain axiom]

[image: inference]

Here's the ontology, which you can load into Protege:

```
@prefix :      <urn:ex:#> .
@prefix ex:    <urn:ex:#> .
@prefix rdf:   <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix owl:   <http://www.w3.org/2002/07/owl#> .
@prefix xsd:   <http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#> .
@prefix rdfs:  <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .

ex:isStudentOf  a               owl:ObjectProperty ;
        owl:propertyChainAxiom  ( ex:studies _:b0 ) .

ex:studies  a   owl:ObjectProperty .

_:b0    owl:inverseOf  ex:teaches .

ex:EL101  a     owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual .

<urn:ex:>  a    owl:Ontology .

ex:Hechinger  a     owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        ex:studies  ex:EL101 .

ex:teaches  a   owl:ObjectProperty .

ex:Cadbury  a       owl:Thing , owl:NamedIndividual ;
        ex:teaches  ex:EL101 .
```

Comment: Perfect.  I added your suggestion to my existing ontology by typing "studies o  inverse (teaches)..." into the SuperProperty Of (Chain) section, like your first screenshot.  Is that turtle syntax at the end of your answer?  I'm still familiarizing myself with the different OWL serializations.

Comment: @MarkMiller The code snippet is Turtle.  OWL has a few serializations:  OWL/XML, FunctionalSyntax, DL syntax, and a mapping to RDF.  RDF is just a data model though, so it has to have a few serializations (e.g., RDF/XML, Turtle/N3, N-Triples).  So the code snippet is the Turtle serialization of the RDF mapping of the OWL ontology.